# Trying to do a calculation on django models

Tags: django, model, integer-division

i have two integer fields  that i want to divide to get the value of 3rd field.
@property
def Pallets_Count(self):
return self.CASES/self.CasesPerPallet

but the result in the database always shows null .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property 
def Pallets_Count(self): 
    return self.CASES/self.CasesPerPallet
```

`@property` will not save anything into your model field. It works like a method. You can call in in your template like a model field `mypost.Pallets_Count`.

If you want to put the result into a database field, you need to override `save` method. But this might not be necessary. Property most likely is enough.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
     # your other fields
     fieldname = models.FloatField()

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.fieldname = self.CASES/self.CasesPerPallet
         super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: what if i needed to have more than one equation for same model ?  how does the save will work in that case ?

Comment: Just add another field and add another Lin in save method.

Comment: Thank you very much  one more question do i have to use Float?   what if i need decimals ?

Comment: what ever you feel you should use. Numberfield is just an example.